# Get output of the command line opened by runas command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, runas

I have been trying to get the output of the RUNAS command, but I have so far been unsuccessful.

I need to get the time of another user, and save it to the a file so another process can read it later.

I have tried many things, but here is an example:
`runas /noprofile /savecred /user:username "cmd /c time > output.txt"`

This does not save the command line output to the file. I was wondering if someone could please help me figure out what I am doing wrong!

I have also tried writing a VBScript to do what I need and I have had no luck so far

Comment: replace `/c` with `/k`. What's does the new window say?

Comment: @Stephan it says "Access is denied"! So this means my problem is that it isn't able to save the output.txt where I want it to? do you know of a way to get around that?

Comment: The `TIME` command prompts for input.  Use `TIME /T` or `ECHO %TIME%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two Problems: the command `time` expects user Input and the new cmd instance opens with working Directory of `c:\Windows\system32` where `username` probably has no write permissions.

Use another command to get the time and give a full path to a Folder with write permissions:

```
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:username "cmd /V:on /C echo !time!>c:\temp\output.txt"
```

Comment: I write to a place where 'username' has write permissions to, but it stills gives me "Access denied". Example: runas /noprofile /savecred /user:psadmin "cmd /k echo %time% > C:\Users\username\Desktop\output.txt", would you have any idea why this could be the case? Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: It was a problem on my end, thank you for your time @Stephan!

Comment: I wonder if you should use: `cmd /V:on /C echo !time!` instead.  Otherwise the %time% variable expands immediately before it executes the command as the runas user.

Comment: @Squashman is totally right; if you run the `runas` command line using `%TIME%` from a command prompt, you'll see that `%TIME%` is expanded already in that command prompt rather than in the new one opened in the `username` context; so you definitely need delayed expansion `!TIME!` to get the desired result...

Comment: @Squashman, Aschipfl: that's right. Edited my answer. `time /t` also should work.

Comment: Yes, but `time /T` returns only hours and minutes while `!TIME!` returns also seconds and even centiseconds...

Comment: depends on what's needed.Just wanted to note.